# Selenium SE record macro for Autocomplete text box

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jquery-autocomplete

I have autocomplete text box, that is JQuery based.
when i record the macro, i am unsure how to select the item that corespond to the value, as you have to select the value that is popping up, i usually click tab on keyboard to get the value selected, but how do i record this to be automated?

My search has only one result, in which it makes it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my implementation was simple, cannot believe i missed this.

```
open    /   
type    id=SelectUser   Dummy, User
click   id=SelectUser   timeout =200
waitForElementPresent   css=li.ac_even  
click   css=li.ac_even  
select  id=FeedBackSource   label=Letter
select  id=TimeReported     label=03:30
select  id=QualityTypeId    label=Positive Feedback
clickAndWait    css=button
```

Where click on the autocomplete text box will trigger action to get results.
The wait for element present, is waiting when the element can be found.
This is better implementation, as you do not have blocked thread for longer than you need

and this follows by click event on li.ac_even which is only one option.

Job Well done:)